# Is there any Demerits of RequiredFieldValidator in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

Today my Senior developer told me to use javascript instead of using  RequiredFieldValidator 
in web form. 
He also told me that its server side validator,

but i read in many article that its a server-side and client-side both and i also know that how to use it in both situation,

Is there any Demerits of using RequiredFieldValidator in real world scenario? I am very curious to know about that.

Thanks

Comment: Well if the functionality of it is enough for you, you can stick with it, and indeed those validator fields can perform both client and server-side validation, although server-side validation should always be considered the most important one. I must admit I most of the time end up using a unique custom validator to validate my forms as it provides a lot of flexibility...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say in this case your senior developer is wrong.

You are correct in saying that the RequiredFieldValidator provides both server and client side validation. It's important to note that JavaScript validation can be bypassed so server side validation is very important.

On the other hand it's also important to provide visual feedback to the user, and the sooner this can be done (i.e. before a postback) the better. In this instance I would suggest that using the server side control is exactly the right choice.

You may find the following [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) useful which is the property to toggle client side validation on or off.